# phpThumb - Invalid hash

Tags: php, hash

Setting up phpThumb for a website, and I want to secure the script by using hash-url's for each image.

I have enabled the security-option in `phpThumb.config.php`:

```
// * Security configuration
$PHPTHUMB_CONFIG['high_security_enabled']    = true;  // if enabled, requires     'high_security_password' set to be set and requires the use of phpThumbURL() function (at the bottom of phpThumb.config.php) to generate hashed URLs
$PHPTHUMB_CONFIG['high_security_password']   = ' ';     // required if 'high_security_enabled' is true, and must be at complex (uppercase, lowercase, numbers, punctuation, etc -- punctuation is strongest, lowercase is weakest; see PasswordStrength() in phpThumb.php). You can use a password generator like http://silisoftware.com/tools/password-random.php to generate a strong password
```

I use the function phpThumbURL() as described in the documentation;

```
    require_once('img/phpThumb.config.php');
    echo '<img src="'.phpThumbURL('src=/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/wall140-73.jpg&amp;w=640&amp;h=400&zc=1').'">';
```

Still, all I get is `Error: Invalid hash`

I got phpThumbs to work without this security-option, but I really do not want to have the script open for anyone to generate thumbnail-images on my server.

I don't understand how the hash can be invalid, and why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

For me helped INFO at the bottom of **phpThumb.config.php**

```
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Function for generating hashed calls to phpThumb if 'high_security_enabled'
// example:
//   require_once('phpThumb/phpThumb.config.php');
//   echo '<img src="'.htmlspecialchars(phpThumbURL('src=/images/pic.jpg&w=50', '/phpThumb/phpThumb.php')).'">';
```

so to make thumb I use function **htmlspecialchars(phpThumbURL(...))**:

```
$path = 'C:\wamp\www\_img_test\\'; // YOUR PATH
require_once($path.'phpThumb\phpThumb.config.php');

$img = '1.jpg'; // YOUR IMAGE
$ParameterString = 'w=200&h=200'; // YOUR PARAMS
$url = 'http://localhost/_img_test/'; // YOUR URL

$path = htmlspecialchars(phpThumbURL('src=../'.$img.'&'.$ParameterString, $url.'phpThumb/phpThumb.php'));
echo '<img src="'.$path.'">'; // YOUR IMAGE
echo $path; // // YOUR IMAGE PATH
```

Of course in phpThumb.config.php set:

```
$PHPTHUMB_CONFIG['high_security_enabled']       = true;
$PHPTHUMB_CONFIG['high_security_password']      = 'V_8r}ZZj-)p4vVx0H6.4'; // YOUR PASSWD from: http://silisoftware.com/tools/password-random.php
$PHPTHUMB_CONFIG['disable_debug']               = true;
```

For me it works.

Answer (score 1):

This may seem silly, but in my config it seems the error I got of "invalid hash" was due to the use of **GLOBALS** in the **phpThumbURL** function at the end of **phpThumb.config.php**, the reason I got an invalid hash match was because the hash check in **phpThumb.php** was matching using the **high_security_password** and **high_security_url_separator**, whilst the function has itself inside the **phpThumb.config.php** was generating it without because despite the **GLOBAL** declaration of **$PHPTHUMB_CONFIG** vars, my server was ignoring it as the php_flag **register_globals** was off.

I merely changed

```
return $path_to_phpThumb.'?'.$ParameterString.$PHPTHUMB_CONFIG['high_security_url_separator'].'hash='.md5($ParameterString.$PHPTHUMB_CONFIG['high_security_password']);
```

to

```
return $path_to_phpThumb.'?'.$ParameterString.'&'.'hash='.md5($ParameterString.'my_high_security_password');
```

Replacing the **high_security_password** and **high_security_url_separator** with their actual values to fix this,

As of **PHP 4.2.0**, the **register_globals** directive defaults to off,

You could I guess use **.htaccess** if your host allows it and add a **.htaccess** entry: `php_flag register_globals on`.

I should note I did not get any error messages to warn me that this was happening, and it took a bit of debugging to back track to the fact that no password or separator was being used in the config to generate the hash which caused the mismatch.

I even ran the **phpThumb.demo.check.php** which indicated that my server was ready to go and did not specify this as a potential problem.

To be fair as **PHP 5** is now the standard on all webservers, with **register globals** off by default, having this required to be enabled for phpThumb to work as default seems like a bit of an oversight as you would expect the class to work under typical defaults for the current version of PHP.

Answer (score 1):

As someone else mentioned, **register_globals** is off by default in most environments and removed as of **PHP 5.4.0** you can still use $GLOBALS though.

Before

```
function phpThumbURL($ParameterString, $path_to_phpThumb='phpThumb.php') {
}
```

put

```
 $GLOBALS['PHPTHUMB_CONFIG'] = $PHPTHUMB_CONFIG;
```

That fixed it in my case

Answer (score 0):

This might seem like a rather silly question, but you did fill in a sufficiently strong high_security_password?

Comment: Alternatively, how big of a problem is it to use the phpThumb script without hash-cryptation?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is going to work when working on a live environment.

It just didn't on my localhost.

Answer (score 0):

I had an same issue, sadly on production so I had to solve it.

There is a function at the bottom of "phpThumb.config.php" which calculates hash from "$parameterString" combined with "high_security_password", this hash is compared to the hash calculated in "phpThumb.php". Everything seems to be ok, but on my case "$parameterString" in "phpThumb.config.php" contained special HTML entities and "$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']" in phpThumb.php didn't. So my solution was to add "htmlspecialchars_decode" for "$parameterString".

phpThumb v.1.7.11

Answer (score 0):

Allthough @user3270861 is right about what causes the issue, there's a much easier solution:

You only need to place `global $PHPTHUMB_CONFIG;` somewhere at the beginning of the *phpThumb.config.php* file, for example right after the `// START USER CONFIGURATION SECTION:` part.

Answer (score 0):

I just bumped into this problem myself.

I was using filters in the form of url params like :

```
&fltr[]=mask|../images/test.png&
```

It was working fine on Chrome but it turns out Firefox changes the

`[]` into `%5B%5D`

So the hash was messed up.

The solution was to replace `[]` by `%5B%5D` in my url. Chrome understood it ok and firefox did not have change it.